# Module build failed: Error: index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation

Tags: angular5

Description of the project: My project is downloading to node_module via package.json

Package.json

```
....
   dependencies:{
       ....
       "@myllc/application-core": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myllc/application-core.git",
       "@myllc/application-shared":"git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myllc/application-shared.git",

   }
   ....
```

Gotting error when doing "npm build":

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@myllc/application-core/index.ts Module
>   build failed: Error:
>   /var/www/frontend-skeleton/node_modules/@myllc/application-core/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property. The missing file
>   seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published
>   libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an
>   issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to
>   package the library using the Angular Package Form at
>   (`https:// goo.gl/jB3GVv`).

This appear after upgrade from Angular4 to Angular5: 
Tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]

  }

}
```

I tried to add

```
"include": [
    "./node_modules/@myllc/**/*"
  ]
```

but there appear same error at deeper folder .ts file. Also founding 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8284
but nothing solved this error.

What is the solution?

Comment: I have the same issue, looks like references are broken. Can't find anything on google.

Comment: Can I see your package.json file?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is found in [index.ts is not part of the compilation. #8284](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8284) by **tapaz1** :

> 2 tsconfig.json files, one at the root of the app, and the other inside the src folder (one level down from the root) named tsconfig.app.json that extends the main tsconfig.json. I explicitly added the package that I needed that wasn't being transpiled by Typescript in the "include" array, and like a lot of people here I was getting the *.spec.ts files included despite having them in "exclude" option, so I removed it from the tsconfig.json. The fix was adding the "exclude" option to the second (extended) tsconfig.app.json file.
>
> **tsconfig.app.json:**
>
> ```
> {
> "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
> "compilerOptions": {
> "outDir": "../dist",
> "baseUrl": "./",
> "module": "es2015",
> "types": []
> },
> "exclude": [
> "../node_modules/your_package/**/*.spec.ts"
> ]
> }
> ```