# I have error while building the angular application

Tags: typescript, compilation

Please help me solve this error. I have seen some solutions on stack overflow, but they are not working for me.

- **Here is the error code**

`ERROR in ./src/app/remedies/Remedy.model.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Volumes/Prince/MyApp/Angular/health/src/app/remedies/Remedy.model.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Volumes/Prince/MyApp/Angular/health/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:674:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/Volumes/Prince/MyApp/Angular/health/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>`

- **links that I have tried but not working**

  1. [Module build failed: Error: index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561600/module-build-failed-error-index-ts-is-missing-from-the-typescript-compilation?rq=1)
  2. [main-aot is missing from the typeScript compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862003/main-aot-is-missing-from-the-typescript-compilation)